# running android apps on linux based chromebook 303c

Tags: software-installation, android, chrome-book, appstream

how do I go about downloading, installing, and running android apps on samsung chromebook model # XE303C12? need step by step guide via terminal. I've tried using crouton but apparently that only works if the chromebook is intel based which mine is NOT. so i'm stuck as to getting this project off the ground. Anybody???

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but the [android SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development) apparently contains an 'emulator based on QEMU', which supports Linux. Might be worth looking into (if there is an ARM version available)?